# Spotipy hangs forever when trying to call method on spotipy object

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, oauth, spotify, spotipy

I have the exact same problem as this person: [Spotipy getting stuck on queries, no return on all functions that query Spotify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71534151/spotipy-getting-stuck-on-queries-no-return-on-all-functions-that-query-spotify?newreg=fc47ea853b5b4e60b3d1f48c2aa43805)

This is how I define the spotipy object:

```
client_credentials_manager = SpotifyClientCredentials(client_id=cid, client_secret=secret)
sp = spotipy.Spotify(client_credentials_manager = client_credentials_manager)
```

and something as simple as this hangs and forces me to restart the kernel.

```
weeknduri = 'spotify:artist:1Xyo4u8uXC1ZmMpatF05PJ'
results = sp.artist_top_tracks(weeknduri)
results
```

I've already tried refreshing the client secret from the spotify developer dashboard, creating a new account and using new client ID and secret, nothing has worked.

Comment: And if you do `print(results)`?

Comment: I'm on a notebook, "print(results)" and just "results" do the same thing. The notebook freezes on the second line, on the artist_top_tracks function.

Comment: ive got the exact same problem wtth no solution in sight